# How to divide int64 in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

How can I divide `int64`?

```
let v: int64 = 100
echo v / 10
```

Error `Error: type mismatch: got <int64, int literal(10)>`

Full example

```
import math

proc sec_to_min*(sec: int64): int = 
  let min = sec / 60 # <= error
  min.round.to_int

echo 100.sec_to_min
```

P.S.

And, is there a way to safely cast `int64` to `int`, so the result would be `int` and not `int64`, with the check for overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been already a bit of discussion over `int64` division in this [issue](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/7920) and probably some improvement to current state can be made. From the above issue:

- a good reason for not having in stdlib float division between `int64` is that it might it may incur in loss of precision and so the user should explicitly convert`int64` to `float`
- still, `float` division between `int` types is present in stdlib
- on 64 bit system `int` *is* `int64` (and so you have division between int64 in 64 bit systems)

For your use case I think the following ([playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2xQn)) should work (better to use div instead of doing float division and then rounding off):

```nim
import math

proc sec_to_min*(sec: int64): int = sec.int div 60

echo 100.sec_to_min

let a = high(int64)
echo a.int  # on playground this does not raise error since int is int64
echo a.int32  # this instead correctly raises error
```

output:

```
1
9223372036854775807
/usercode/in.nim(9)      in
/playground/nim/lib/system/fatal.nim(49) sysFatal
Error: unhandled exception: value out of range: 9223372036854775807 notin -2147483648 .. 2147483647 [RangeError]
```

P.S.: as you see above standard conversion has range checks

Answer (score 2):

Apparently division between int64 types is terribly dangerous because it invokes an undying horde of bike shedding, but at least you can create your own operator:

```
proc `/`(x, y: int64): int64 = x div y

let v: int64 = 100
echo v / 10
```

Or

```
proc `/`(x, y: int64): int64 = x div y

import math

proc sec_to_min*(sec: int64): int = 
  int(sec / 60)

echo 100.sec_to_min
```

With regards to the `int64` to `int` conversion, I'm not sure that makes much sense since most platforms will run `int` as an alias of `int64`. But of course you could be compiling/running on a 32 bit platform, where the loss would be tragic, so you can still do runtime checks:

```
let a = int64.high

echo "Unsurprising but potentially wrong ", int(a)

proc safe_int(big_int: int64): int =
  if big_int > int32.high:
    raise new_exception(Overflow_error, "Value is too high for 32 bit platforms")
  int(big_int)

echo "Reachable code ", safe_int(int32.high)
echo "Unreachable code ", safe_int(a)
```

Also, if you are running into confusing minute, hour, day conversions, you might want to look [into distinct types](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-distinct-type) to avoid adding months to seconds (or do so in a more safe way).